# Scroll fica sempre na base de uma div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou trazendo informações automaticamente de uma base de dados, do qual cria-se uma scroll em uma div. O problema é que tenho que ficar descendo a scroll para acompanhar as informações que aparecem na tela. Como eu faria para que a scroll descesse automaticamente com as informações, independente da quantidade que o banco de dados traz? Testei esse código, porém não funcionou:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#resultados").scrollTop($("#resultados")[0].scrollHeight);
</script>

<div id="resultados" style="overflow: scroll">

Aqui aparece os resultados

</div>
```

Comment: Não entendi, podias recriar um exemplo disto no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) e explicar um pouco melhor o que estás a tentar fazer?

Comment: Estás a adicionar mais do que um elemento com a mesma ID `#resultados`? ver o HTML e/ou um jsFiddle seria bom...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que definir um `height` fixo para sua `div`.

```js
$("#resultados").scrollTop($("#resultados")[0].scrollHeight);
```

```css
#resultados {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resultados" style="overflow: scroll">

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis doloremque dolorum expedita accusamus error asperiores harum ipsam culpa odit blanditiis rerum aperiam et praesentium ea autem, esse veniam nulla deleniti!

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic molestiae ratione iusto laudantium illum velit sit reprehenderit sed officiis consequuntur alias fugit optio aspernatur voluptatum dolores earum, aut. Eum, reiciendis?
  </p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore consectetur reprehenderit et incidunt laudantium fugiat sed commodi reiciendis rerum beatae sit repudiandae ipsum rem facere neque, autem? Reiciendis, modi eveniet!</p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae, asperiores dolores illo, error nihil incidunt hic vero, pariatur tempora tempore corporis! Repellat doloremque et cum neque blanditiis nam, quaerat alias!
  </p>
</div>
```